Copy 50 records into 5 million records either using python or SQL
I have a txt file with 8 columns and 50 rows. I have two requests:

I want to copy these 50 rows and create a 5 million record file (i.e. same set of 50 records copied over to create 5 million record file).
I want to use two different delimeter (existing one is a comma - I want tab and pipe as well)

What is the easiest way to do this? Is Python code will be simpler OR loading this into a SQL and writing query to copy paste will work?

Which delimiters do you want to use where?

First, read in the input file. Then replicate the contents as many times as you'd like. Then write out the contents to the output file
with open('path/to/input') as infile:
    contents = infile.readlines() + ['\n']

numInputs = len(contents)-1  # should be 50 in this example
numOutputs = 5 * 10**6  # 5 million
numReplications = numOutputs//numInputs  # won't exceed numOutputs

contents = ''.join(contents)

with open('path/to/output', 'w') as outfile:
    for _ in range(numReplications):
        outfile.write(contents)



Won't the iteration time out for 100000 times?

@SuramuthuR: I'm not sure I understand how a timeout will occur in this case

Python is more straightforward for this, especially since it's more flexible with file handling and you won't have to deal with SQL.
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'yourfile.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

df_repeated = pd.concat([df] * (5000000 // len(df)), ignore_index=True)

df_repeated.to_csv('output_tab.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
df_repeated.to_csv('output_pipe.txt', sep='|', index=False)

print("Files created successfully.")

